Find the roots of the dirichlet kernel convolved with two impulses

The Dirichlet kernel is defined as
$$D_M(\omega) = \frac{\sin(\frac{M+1}{2}\omega)}{\sin(\frac{\omega}{2})} \tag1$$
Multiplying $D_M(\omega)$ by a complex exponential is
$$W(\omega) = e^{-j\frac{M}{2}\omega}\frac{\sin(\frac{M+1}{2}\omega)}{\sin(\frac{\omega}{2})} \tag2$$
Convolving $W(\omega)$ by two impulses $H(\omega) = \delta[\omega-\omega_0]+\delta[\omega+\omega_0]$ and setting up the equation to find the roots yields
$$e^{-j(\omega-\omega_0) M/2} \frac{\sin(\frac{M+1}{2}(\omega-\omega_0))}{\sin(\frac{1}{2}(\omega-\omega_0))} + 
e^{-j(\omega+\omega_0) M/2} \frac{\sin(\frac{M+1}{2}(\omega+\omega_0))}{\sin(\frac{1}{2}(\omega+\omega_0))} = 0 \tag3$$
$M$ and $\omega_0$ are known, and $\omega$ is the unknown. $M$ is a positive integer. I want to solve this equation with respect to $\omega$. Here is the progress so far: -

If $\alpha = \frac{\omega-\omega_0}{2}$ and $\beta = \frac{\omega+\omega_0}{2}$ this makes the equation more managable
$$e^{-jM\alpha} \frac{\sin([M+1]\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha)} = - e^{-jM\beta} \frac{\sin([M+1]\beta)}{\sin(\beta)} \tag4$$
Noticing that $\beta = \alpha + \omega_0$ and inserting yields
$$\frac{\sin([M+1]\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha)} = - e^{-jM\omega_0} \frac{\sin([M+1][\alpha+\omega_0])}{\sin(\alpha + \omega_0)} \tag5$$
From here, I can't see anywhere to go further. Can anyone help me onwards?
The function in $(3)$ is complex valued. I have plotted the function in $(3)$ setting $M=19$ and $\omega_0 = 0.1\pi$. Both the real and imaginary part of the function cross zero at the same value of $\omega$ and it seems to be happening at $\omega = \frac{2\pi}{M+1}k$ where $k$ is a positive integer: -


Inspect the $y(x)= \dfrac{\sin x}{x} $ graph. It oscillates reducingly between $\pm1$ for $\omega_0>0.$
Value of y at $x=0$ is the highest at $y=1$. For positive sign of RHS the oscillating graph never cuts the highest value at top point tangent. so $\omega_0=0$ is the only real solution.
Similarly for negative RHS sign the negative graph nevers cut the highest tangent value. Again, $\omega_0=0$ is the only real solution.

I think there is a misunderstanding. My question is regarding a dirichlet kernel $\frac{\sin((M+1/2)x)}{\sin(x/2)}$ and not a sinc function.
